# Is "Masterpieces of the British Museum" cancelled?

Tags: cancellation, masterpieces-of-the-british-museum

From the [BBC Four](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b0074spf), I can see that the last episode of *Masterpieces of the British Museum* was aired in 2009. In the "Next episode" it says "Coming soon".

[IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3957544/) has the ending year void yet, like it is still ongoing. However, we are ten years  after the 4th episode.

Are the rest two episodes going to be aired, or is it cancelled?

Comment: [All six episodes are available on DVD](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Masterpieces-British-Museum-DVD/dp/B000MM0GSW), so the two not mentioned on the website do exist. I suspect this is simply a case of the BBC forgetting to update their site, but I'll see if I can dig deeper.

Comment: Oh amazing @F1Krazy, I think you are right! To be honest, I think you should convert your comment into an answer. :)

Comment: @gsamaras It still doesn't answer why they were not aired, though (or if they were).

Comment: Indeed @NapoleonWilson, neither why IMDb doesn't have an ending year to this series of episodes. However, I know now that all six exist, and I buy them from Άμαζον. PS: Thanks for creating that tag for me!

Comment: @gsamaras IMDb lists the last two episodes in the episode list, those being "Dürer's Rhinoceros" and "The Aztec Double-Headed Serpent".

Comment: Charles, you are right, if I click on the Episodes Guide, I see all six of them, thanks! The fact that IMDd lacks an ending year consumed all my attention... @F1Krazy, seems no one has come up with a better, I would suggest you to post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't find any evidence that the show wasn't cancelled, I also can't find any evidence that it *was*. The two episodes not listed on the BBC website ("Dürer's Rhinoceros" and "The Aztec Double-Headed Serpent") both definitely exist - they're available in [the show's DVD box set](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Masterpieces-British-Museum-DVD/dp/B000MM0GSW) and [IMDb lists them](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3957544/episodes?ref_=tt_ql_tv_1) as having aired in July 2006 - there's no precise air date, but also no indication that they *didn't* air. (Incidentally, other sources claim a 2009 air date.)

Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence - I believe the most likely answer that the series *did* air to completion, but nobody bothered to update the BBC or IMDb websites. It hardly seems like the kind of show that would have had rabid followers frantically updating its IMDb/Wikipedia/TV Tropes pages after every episode came out (in fact, it doesn't even *have* Wikipedia or TV Tropes pages!)